# USB Storage w/ OS on HDD

Tags: macos, networking, nas, usb-storage

I want to plug a USB storage HDD into a Raspberry Pi and use it as a NAS. The HDD is from my old Macbook, so it will have an OS on it. Is it still possible to treat it like an extra HDD and retrieve files off it?

Comment: Are you asking if you can plug in a USB HDD into your Raspberry PI?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure you can do that. I want to know if I can access files off an HDD with an OS installed the same way you would normal use a clean HDD on a USB Storage device.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between what you want to do and my question to clarify your question.

Comment: It's possible to create a NAS device by plugging an empty HDD into a USB Storage device and plugging that into a rpi. I want to know if having an OS on the HDD will make it unusable for this purpose.

Comment: Why would it make it unusable.  The os your running is Linux.

Comment: The OS is Mac Snow Leopard.

Comment: How are you running OS X on a Raspberry Pi?  You can connect the HDD to the Raspberry Pi, it being able ot read the file system, i something entirely separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will the hard drive be usable?  Yes.

The question is whether or not the OS installed on your Raspberry Pi will read the Mac's HFS file system.  I believe HFS support is in most Linux's by now... but Im not 100% sure.

Comment: what about it??

Comment: On another Mac, will I see the OS on the drive and be able to navigate to the folders I want as if I was on the old laptop it came from? If I backed up the files and reformatted the HDD, would it be possible to make it platform agnostic?

Comment: windows cannot read hfs without 3rd party tools

Comment: I hadn't even thought about that. So is it correct to say Raspian will be reading and writing the OSX files, and my newer MacBook, which I will be creating and editing files on, will be saving the files back onto the HDD through the rpi? I think I have some more research to do.

Comment: While it's true that windows can't read HFS, it's unlikely they'll be running Windows on the pi, and once the drive is shared via CIFS/SAMBA/AFP the underlying filesystem is abstracted to network hosts (like possible windows clients) As for getting it accessed and shared on the pi to begin with, under raspbian you'll need to install several packages to get HFS+ support, but there are plenty of tutorials out there.